# How to end a C++ program after error?

Tags: c++, error-handling

I am refactoring an old code, and one of the things I'd like to address is the way that errors are handled. I'm well aware of exceptions and how they work, but I'm not entirely sure they're the best solution for the situations I'm trying to handle.

In this code, if things don't validate, there's really no reason or advantage to unwind the stack. We're done. There's no point in trying to save the ship, because it's a non-interactive code that runs in parallel through the Sun Grid Engine. The user can't intervene. What's more, these validation failures don't really represent exceptional circumstances. They're expected.

So how do I best deal with this? One thing I'm not sure I want is an exit point in every class method that can fail. That seems unmaintainable. Am I wrong? Is it acceptable practice to just call `exit()` or `abort()` at the failure point in codes like this? Or should I throw an exception all the way back to some generic catch statement in main? What's the advantage?

Comment: Is there any good from recovering from an exception or you just want to exit whenever an error happens ? Isn't it a little too much when your application crashes every time an error occurs ?

Comment: I am using exceptions and the like for non-fatal problems. I'm really trying to address the fatal error situation here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Throwing an exception to be caught in main and then exiting means your RAII resource objects get cleaned up. On most systems this isn't needed for a lot of resource types. The OS will clean up memory, file handles, etc. (though I've used a system where failing to free memory meant it remained allocated until system restart, so leaking on program exit wasn't a good idea.)

But there are other resource types that you may want to release cleanly such as network or database connections, or a mechanical device you're driving and need to shut down safely. If an application uses a lot of such things then you may prefer to throw an exception to unwind the stack back to main, and then exit.

So the appropriate method of exiting depends on the application. If an application knows it's safe then calling _Exit(), abort(), exit(), or quickexit() may be perfectly reasonable. (Library code shouldn't call these, since obviously the library has no idea whether its safe for every application that will ever use the library.) If there is some critical clean up that must be performed before an application exits but you know it's limited, then the application can register that clean up code via atexit() or at_quick_exit().

So basically decide what you need cleaned up, document it, implement it, and try to make sure it's tested.

Answer (score 4):

It is acceptable to terminate the program if it cannot handle the error gracefully. There are few things you can do:

- Call [`abort()`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/abort.3.html) if you need a core dump.
- Call [`exit()`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/exit.3.html) if you want to give a chance to run to those routines registered with [`atexit()`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/atexit.3.html) (that is most likely to call destructors for global C++ objects).
- Call [`_exit()`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/exit.2.html) to terminate a process immediately.

There is nothing wrong with using those functions as long as you understand what you are doing, know your other choices, and choose that path willingly. After all, that's why those functions exist. So if you don't think it makes any sense to try to handle the error or do anything else when it happens - go ahead. What I would probably do is try to log some informative message (say, to syslog), and call `_exit`. If logging fails - call `abort` to get a core along the termination.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest to call global function

```
void stopProgram() {
  exit(1);
}
```

Later you can change it's behavior, so it is maintainable.

Comment: It's `void exit(int status)`, not `void exit()`.

Answer (score 1):

As you pointed out, having an `exit` or `abort` thrown around throughout your code is not maintainable ... additionally, there may be a mechanism in the future that could allow you to recover from an error, or handle an error in a more graceful manner than simply exiting, and if you've already hard-coded this functionality in, then it would be very hard to undo.

Throwing an exception that is caught in `main()` is your best-bet at this point that will also give you flexibility in the future should you run the code under a different scenario that will allow you to recover from errors, or handle them differently.  Additionally, throwing exceptions could help should you decide to add more debugging support, etc., as it will give you spots to implement logging features and record the program state from isolated and maintainable points in the software before you decide let the program exit.